# Qualys SslLabs for default virtualhost reports certificate mismatch from second virtualhost certificate on a single ip

Tags: ssl, apache2, virtualhost

I have two name-based virtual hosts on a single IP.
A test on Qualys SSL LABS on the first virtual host (default) reported a certificate mismatch for the second virtual host canonical names, reporting "this site only works with SNI support".
If I disable the second virtual host the test ends right.
A test i made by openssl s_client doesn't report any issue:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.mydomain.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = www.mydomain.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGXTCCBUWgAwIBAgISA9y+4P5bPxkfLq3K4eAzMsYXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MEoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MSMwIQYDVQQD
..............................................................
+/NQyC6DsWJcID5sO7K++GBEl4iyHGQWCHlfY13Vpk8Iz81ov5/hHVtwZSZ60qKD
MRvIfmb9LzBHqdkL/Wjxt7gJC6YtuEYrIoP5+w2vZnLrG2jJCSWj6N8R+vh0Sh8e
qQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = www.mydomain.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3628 bytes and written 401 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 19XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX07
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXE
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - b6 72 41 25 a1 5f c8 bd-7b 8f fb 8c fc c2 0d f8   .rA%._..{.......
.............................................................................
    00f0 - 00 66 31 2a a3 9e 1c 73-95 16 56 b8 71 45 32 cc   .f1*...s..V.qE2.

    Start Time: 1578821067
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: F0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC6
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5E
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - b6 72 41 25 a1 5f c8 bd-7b 8f fb 8c fc c2 0d f8   .rA%._..{.......
    0010 - 03 94 2e 7e bb e9 58 3d-64 ad 31 73 50 03 5f 91   ...~..X=d.1sP._.
.................................................................................
    00f0 - 20 83 7f 51 a0 e7 88 c8-f6 05 23 55 6e e3 34 c6    ..Q......#Un.4.

    Start Time: 1578821067
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK



My default virtualhost has a ServerName www.mydomain.com directive in apache2.conf and its virtualhost file has one too.
The Qualys SSL Labs test for www.mydomain.com reports a `Alternative names  www.mysecond-domain.com   MISMATCH`.
I don't undestand why Qualys SSL LABS keeps on involving the second virtualhost when i'm testing the default virtualhost.
Regards
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable and configure default-ssl.conf in */etc/apache2/sites-available*, in my case Ubuntu 18.04. **Do not use 000-default-ssl.conf.**
I assume that vhosts are already well configured.
With command a2ensite you enable default-ssl.conf.
Then edit and change config.
Yo have to be sure that virtual host is <VirtualHost *:443> and not <VirtualHost_default_:443>.

Check this config. This will make SNI works. Hope you can fix it.

*nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf*

```
     <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
              # <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
                # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
                # modules, e.g.
                LogLevel info ssl:warn

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
                # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
                # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
                # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
                # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on

                #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
                #   the ssl-cert package. See
                #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
                #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
                #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

                #   Server Certificate Chain:
                #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
                #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
                #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
                #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
                #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
                #   certificate for convinience.
                #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

                #   Certificate Authority (CA):
                #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
                #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
                #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

                #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
                #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
                #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
                #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
                #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

              
                #   SSL Engine Options:
                #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>


        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Also set this in ports.conf**
*/etc/apache2/ports.conf*

```
Listen  80

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>
```

Be sure mod_ssl.c and mod_gnutls.c are enabled. If not, set a2enmod mod_ssl.c and a2enmod mod_gnutls.c. Then execute *systemctl reload apache2*